# Poor FPS with Wine (WoW)

Tags: wine, games, opengl

I just recently installed Ubuntu and tried to run WoW on it. It runs fine, but performance is very bad compared to Win7.
I do use OpenGL instead of DX on Ubuntu `SET gxApi "opengl"` also direct rendering is enabled - `glxinfo | grep rendering` gives me `direct rendering: Yes`.

So I think that I did everything correctly, my results differs from Win7 dramatically.

> Ubuntu (OpenGL): Avg FPS 35-45
>  Win7 (DX9): Avg FPS 50-60
>   Win7 (DX11): Avg FPS 60-80
>  Win7 (OpenGL): 50

The enviroment was very still, no players running whatsoever, graphical settings were same for both platforms. Is it normal? Is there any way of achieving same FPS on Ubuntu as on Win7 or it is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling Compiz and run WoW again.

You can do that simply by choosing on your login screen "classic gnome desktop" without effects, or use the compiz settings manager to turn off compiz.

That will do the trick. Hope this helps. *For the HOOOOOOORDE!!!!*